# Local External Data Source into Local DB Environment

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I have been trying to create an External Data Source locally in SSMS v18.11.1 using SQL Server 2019.

I have PolyBase enabled the master key and credential have also been created.

Azure code (works):

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE [MasterDataSource]
WITH (
      TYPE = RDBMS,
      LOCATION = N'{location}.database.windows.net',
      DATABASE_NAME = N'{DatabaseName}',
      CREDENTIAL = [MasterDbCred]
     );
```

Local (not working):

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE SQLServerInstance2
WITH (
      LOCATION = 'sqlserver://{HostName}:1433' ,
      CREDENTIAL = MasterDbCred
     )
```

I am using `SELECT HOST_NAME()` to get the hostname.

When running the local script above no matter what `LOCATION` used, I get:

> OLE DB provider "MSOLEDBSQL" for linked server "(null)" returned message "Login timeout expired".
>
> OLE DB provider "MSOLEDBSQL" for linked server "(null)" returned message "A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.".

Which would suggest it's not connecting to local.

Other external data sources work, for example, I have a `BLOB_STORAGE` working locally, but this is to an external location.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE [external_data]
WITH (
      TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE,
      LOCATION = N'https://storage.blob.core.windows.net/datacontainer'
     );
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: "Local DB" or "LocalDB"? Are you trying to connect to the *current* instance from LocalDB? That's not going to work because LocalDB instances aren't reachable over TCP/IP. Connecting to a local (dedicated) SQL Server should work, though.

Comment: LocalDB, so (local) . etc... can you elaborate on the local dedicated SQL server, are you saying install another instance of SQL Server and connect to that making it the external data source, I think that may work.

Comment: Looks like normal connectivity troubleshooting?  Where is the SQL instance you're running polybase on?  Can you connect from that box to the target server using SSMS, SQLCMD, or Linked Server?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I have to installed another instance of SQL server and called it SQL2019, I am following the docs on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-data-source-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15&tabs=dedicated section F, with no luck. I am getting the same connectivity error and my new instance is running on port 30604, when trying to connect without the port as specified in the docs it also is not working, any thoughts?

Comment: Can you connect from that box to the target server using SSMS, SQLCMD, or Linked Server?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Yes using SSSMS with server .\SQL2019 and windows authentication.

Comment: And have you verified using SQL Server Configuration Manager that the target instance has TCP/IP enabled, and you can connect to its listenting port with test-netconnection?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft that was it mate, enabling TCP/IP on the second instance worked, feel free to post the answer, and ill mark it correct. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like normal connectivity troubleshooting.

Verify using SQL Server Configuration Manager that the target instance has TCP/IP enabled, and you can connect to its listening port with `test-netconnection`.

Remember SQL Server Developer and Express Editions have TCP/IP disabled by default.